# Apache Flink output to csv file for each GroupedDataSet

Tags: scala, grouping, apache-flink

I want to output to csv every groupedDataSet.

Example of the data:

```
A,123
B,200
A,400
B,400
```

So my desired output is:

file 1:

```
A,123
A,400
```

file 2:

```
B,200
B,400
```

So basically a simple code for `exampleData`:

```
exampleData.groupBy(0).sortGroup(1, Order.ASCENDING)
```

Now I want to output each groupedDataSet to a different CSV. What is the best practice to achieve this?

I'm using Scala version 2.11.12, and Flink version 1.11.0

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a bucketing sink, but that's currently only supported for streaming jobs, not batch. Flink 1.12 has unified batch & streaming, so in theory that might work for you. I implemented my own bucketing sink for batch jobs, but it seems to have some issues with recent versions of Hadoop, which I need to debug.