# Apache Flink dump to multiple files by key (group)

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'm doing some processing on data, and I want to dump the processed data to multiple files, based on the group.

Example of the data:

```
A,123
B,200
A,400
B,400
```

So my desired output is:

file 1:

```
A,123
A,400
```

file 2:

```
B,200
B,400
```

(The number of files is based on the number of groups).

So basically a simple code for `exampleData`:

```
exampleData.groupBy(0).sortGroup(1, Order.ASCENDING)
```

The type now is `GroupedDataSet`. I want to output each groupedDataSet to a different CSV. How can I do this? I tried using `reduceGroup`, so I can work with each group individually, but I couldn't make it to work.

I'm using Scala version 2.11.12, and Flink version 1.11.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Flink output to csv file for each GroupedDataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527882/apache-flink-output-to-csv-file-for-each-groupeddataset)

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski It would if there was an answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't this question just a full duplicate of the previous one ?

Comment: What did you try with `reduceGroup`?